# Validation of multiple radio buttons using Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I have this python script that I use to send a list of dictionaries to a web page.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms.fields import RadioField

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

class SimpleForm(Form):
    relevance = RadioField('Label', choices=[('0','A'), ('1','B'), ('2','C')])

@app.route('/',methods=['post','get'])
def hello_world():
    form = SimpleForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print form.relevance
    else:
        print form.errors

    stuff = {
            "text": "blah",
            "other": "random",
            "title": "21",
            "radios": form
        }
    stuff2 = {
            "text": "blah2",
            "other": "random2",
            "title": "22",
            "radios": form
        }
    all_stuff = {
        "mall": [stuff, stuff2]
    }
    return render_template('example.html', **all_stuff)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is `example.html`:

```
<form method="post">
    {% for a in mall %}
        {{ a.other }}<br>
        {{ a.title }}<br>
        {{ a.text }}<br>
        {{ a.radios.relevance }}<br>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

This prints the two dictionaries but the Radio Buttons act like a single set of radio buttons. Here I have shown 2 dictionaries but I will be having like 50 dictionaries whose radio button values I have to submit. How can I do that? Whenever I submit I get `{'csrf_token': ['CSRF token missing']}`

Another thing is that why does this way of rendering Radio buttons result in a vertical list of radio buttons? Is there a way I can a get a horizontal representation of the buttons?

Comment: Is it because all your dictionaries point to one instance of the form? Seeing the rendered html might help.

Answer (score 0):

'radio' field allow you to check only one button.

To select multiple options, you must use 'checkbox' field.